# Q: Find all functions that are analytic and satisfy $(\operatorname{Re}(f(z)))^2 = \operatorname{Im}(f(z))$

Tags: complex-analysis

I've been trying to find all functions $f(z):\Bbb{C}\longrightarrow\Bbb{C}$ that are analytic and satisfy

$$(\operatorname{Re}(f(z)))^2 = \operatorname{Im}(f(z))$$

After plugging in $f(z)=x+iy$, I got $f(z)=x+ix^2$.

These kind of functions never satisfy Cauchy-Riemann equations, since $\mathcal u_x=1 \neq 0=v_y$.

Does it follow from this argumentation that no such analytic $f(z)$ exists?

Comment: $f(z) = 0$ works, as do constant functions of that form like $f(z) = 3 + 9 \cdot i$.

Comment: The partial derivative $u_x$ in the Cauchy-Riemann equations is taken with respect to $x = \operatorname{Re} z$, not $x=\operatorname{Re} f$

Answer (score 5):

You might have rushed your analysis a little bit. The condition you have given is equivalent to saying that
$$ f(x+  iy) = u(x,y) + i u(x,y)^2$$
Computing the Cauchy-Riemann equations we have
$$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = 2u\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$$
and
$$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = -2u\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$$
Combining these two we have
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = - 4 u^2 \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \iff \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \left(1 + 4u^2\right) = 0$$
Since $1 + 4u^2 > 0$ for all $u \in \mathbb{R}$ we must have $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = 0$. In similar fashion we may also compute
$$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = -  4u^2 \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \iff\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \left(1 + 4u^2\right) = 0 $$
From which we may conclude that $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = 0$. So $u(x,y)$ must be a constant function. Since we did not specify any specific value of the constant function $u(x,y)$ then it follows that it works for all values. Thus functions with a constant real part which satisfy the hypothesis you have given are all solutions.

Comment: You, too, may have rushed your analysis a bit ;) We get $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = 2u\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$$ not $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = 2u\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$$

Comment: Indeed I too have rushed my analysis a bit... going to fix that up right now.

Answer (score 4):

Another kind of solution: Note that ${\rm Im}(f(z))\geq 0$ for all $z$. Hence if we put $g(z)=\exp(if(z))$, we have $|g(z)|=\exp(-{\rm Im}(f(z))\leq 1$ for all $z$. By Liouville's theorem, $g$ is constant, and $f$ is also a constant, of the form $c+ic^2$, $c\in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Very nice, +1!

Comment: This is pretty clever. If you want to bring out the big guns, Picard's little theorem says analytic functions miss no more point in their image. So you can stop after your first sentence.

Answer (score 1):

If as usual we set

$z = x + iy \tag{1}$

and

$f(z) = u(x, y) + iv(x, y), \tag{2}$

then the condition

$(\operatorname{Re}(f(z)))^2 = \operatorname{Im}(f(z)) \tag{3}$

may be written

$v = u^2;\tag{4}$

thus $f(z)$ becomes

$f(z) =  u(x, y) + iu^2(x, y).  \tag{5}$

Since $f(z)$ is holomorphic, $u(x, y)$ and $v(x, y) =  u^2(x, y)$ are harmonic; that is,

$\nabla^2u = 0 \tag{6}$

and

$\nabla^2 u^2 = 0.  \tag{7}$

We compute $\nabla^2u^2$; we have

$\nabla^2 u^2 = \nabla \cdot \nabla u^2$
$= \nabla \cdot (2u \nabla u) = 2\nabla u \cdot \nabla u + 2u \nabla^2u$
$= 2 \vert \nabla u \vert^2, \tag{8}$

using (6); in deriving (8), we have also used the standard identity

$\nabla \cdot (gX) = \nabla g \cdot X + g \nabla \cdot X, \tag{9}$

holding for differeniable scalar functions $g$ and vector fields $X$; for more, see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus_identities.  It follows from (7) and (8) that

$\vert \nabla u \vert^2 = 0, \tag{10}$

or

$\vert \nabla u \vert = 0, \tag{11}$

or

$\nabla u = 0; \tag{12}$

we conclude that $u(x, y)$ must be a real constant $c$; it follows then that $v(x, y) = c^2$ and, finally $f(z)$ is a complex constant of the form

$f(z) = c + ic^2, \tag{13}$

where $c \in \Bbb R$.

***Nota Bene:***  The technique used above, *viz.* showing that $\nabla u = 0$, may be applied to other, similar questions as well; see for example the

***Related Problem:***

[Can we conclude that $u^{-1}+iu$ is constant?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/996320/can-we-conclude-that-u-1iu-is-constant)